# Keeping focus on a textbox except when in certain other elements

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to keep focus on a textbox for a touch screen kiosk in the event someone clicks out of it. However, I'd like to give them the option to move the cursor to a drop down box too. With the code below, it's still jumping back to the textbox even when in my designated class.

Am I using activeElement properly in my if statement?

```js
this.textbox = $('<input class="full-width" type="text" tabindex=1/>'); //Change the tab index number to the position you need it to be
this.host.append(this.textbox);
var _this = this;
this.textbox.blur(async function() {
  if (!document.activeElement.className.match("dp-combobox__input dp-combobox__input--has-clear dp-combobox__input--has-arrow DropDownBoxes")) {
    function sleep(duration) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve()
        }, duration * 250)
      })
    };
    await sleep(1);
    _this.textbox.focus();
    _this.textbox.select();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="dp-combobox__input dp-combobox__input--has-clear dp-combobox__input--has-arrow DropDownBoxes" style="font-family:Roboto;font-size:25px;color:Black;;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none;;height:100%" tabindex="-1">
```

Comment: it would help a lot if you added some html so the problem can easily be reproduced here. Also if you moved your function `sleep` out to the top level it would help readability a lot.

Comment: @AndrewLohr did i make the corrections correctly? I make the text box in JS and append it to the host and I added that to the code to reflect. I also added the html for the dropdown. My solution is funky, it's a nocode environment, so I drag the dropdowns onto my form, then I add JS components which is the code above.

Comment: Is your attempt to match the class actually working? Try outputting the actual value for className for that element to see if it is what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is checking the active element right after the text box loses focus. There is a instant where the active element is actually the `body` of the document before the dropdown becomes the active element.

You can fix this by simply moving your sleep above your check for active element. I have another solution in the second snippet you can take a look at as well.

```js
this.textbox = $('<input class="full-width" type="text" tabindex=1/>'); //Change the tab index number to the position you need it to be

//this.host.append(this.textbox);

$("body").append(this.textbox); //only for this example since idk what this.host is

var _this = this;

this.textbox.blur(async function() {
  await sleep(1);
  if (!document.activeElement.className.match("dp-combobox__input dp-combobox__input--has-clear dp-combobox__input--has-arrow DropDownBoxes")) {
    _this.textbox.focus();
    _this.textbox.select();
  }
});

function sleep(duration) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve()
    }, duration * 250)
  })
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="dp-combobox__input dp-combobox__input--has-clear dp-combobox__input--has-arrow DropDownBoxes" style="font-family:Roboto;font-size:25px;color:Black;;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none;;height:100%" tabindex="-1">
```

You can also look at [focusout's relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget) property. It will tell you the next element that was clicked when a certain element loses focus.

```js
this.textbox = $('<input class="full-width" type="text" tabindex=1/>'); //Change the tab index number to the position you need it to be

//this.host.append(this.textbox);

$("body").append(this.textbox); //only for this example since idk what this.host is

var _this = this;

this.textbox.on("focusout", event => {
  let nextElement = event.relatedTarget;
  if (!nextElement || !event.relatedTarget.className.match("dp-combobox__input dp-combobox__input--has-clear dp-combobox__input--has-arrow DropDownBoxes")) {
    _this.textbox.focus();
    _this.textbox.select();
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="dp-combobox__input dp-combobox__input--has-clear dp-combobox__input--has-arrow DropDownBoxes" style="font-family:Roboto;font-size:25px;color:Black;;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none;;height:100%" tabindex="-1">
```

Another "catch-all" solution could be to just set an interval for every second and do your check. This way you don't have to keep track of losing focus (blur) for the text box and having to sleep.

This case also handles the initial case where the input box isn't focused/active to begin with. This will focus on the text box on load too.

```js
this.textbox = $('<input class="full-width" type="text" tabindex=1/>'); //Change the tab index number to the position you need it to be

//this.host.append(this.textbox);

$("body").append(this.textbox); //only for this example since idk what this.host is

var _this = this;

setInterval(() => {
  if (!document.activeElement.className.match("dp-combobox__input dp-combobox__input--has-clear dp-combobox__input--has-arrow DropDownBoxes")) {
    _this.textbox.focus();
    _this.textbox.select();
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="dp-combobox__input dp-combobox__input--has-clear dp-combobox__input--has-arrow DropDownBoxes" style="font-family:Roboto;font-size:25px;color:Black;;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none;;height:100%" tabindex="-1">
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll give this a go. I didn't even think of the body being a variable in this, I assumed when the blur happens it was instantly in the new element.

Comment: no problem, I also added another solution using the `focusout` event that you may be interested in.

Comment: I went with the solution which involved moving the sleep. I forgot while doing this the sleep function is vital. We're using this chrome extension to populate a keyboard on the screen, and the auto focus is way too fast for the keyboard. when you blur from the text box, and focus back, the keyboard is still in the process of closing down.

Thanks again!